# Looking for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers

I am looking for the sum of the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+2}}$$

where $F_{n}$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number. I was thinking about splitting the fraction into 2 like in the case of $\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$, but do not see how it should work in this particular case.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can use the expansion from [Euler Binet Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula), and simplify. I am not getting any closed form solution, but maybe the limit would be easier.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729315/sum-frac11-times2-frac11-times3-frac12-times5-frac13-times8?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{f(n)f(n+2)} &=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\color{red} {f(n+1)}}{f(n)\color{red} {f(n+1)}f(n+2)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{f(n+2)-f(n)}{f(n)f(n+1)f(n+2)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{f(n)f(n+1)}-\frac{1}{f(n+1)f(n+2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{f(1)f(2)}-\frac{1}{f(N+1)f(N+2)}\end{align}.

Comment: This looks copied and pasted from somewhere. You should cite your sources.

Comment: no I did it by my self . but my latex don't work here . it was an easy problem to me .

Comment: Thank you "david H' for editing may latex codes.

Comment: Seems like the main reason your latex wasn't working was that you forgot the dollar signs. I edited your response to make your latex code compatible with our site.