# Finding a closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(n)F(n+2k)}$, where $F(n)$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

So, I want to find the closed value for the sequence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F(n)F(n+2k)}$$
Here by $F(n)$ I mean the $n$-th term of Fibonacci Sequence.

I got motivated for this by the YouTube video ["Using partial fractions to evaluate two Fibonacci reciprocal sums"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0P_EFWriq-A) by Prof. Michael Penn. So in the end of video he says for finding this for the general case : k. So i tried it and here is what i did:-

Let
$$\frac{1}{F(n)F(n+2k)} = \frac{A}{F(n)} + \frac{B}{F(n+2k)}$$

so by rearranging we can say that: $AF(n+2k) + BF(n) = 1$

Now let $C_0 = F(n+2k)$

then $C_1 = F(n+2k-1) + F(n+2k-2)$

so   $C_2 = 2F(n+2k-2) + F(n+2k-3)$

then by induction we can prove that if i repeat this process j times then $C_j = F(j+1)F(n+2k-j) + F(j)F(n+2k-j-1)$

So now let $j = 2k - 1$
F
then $C_{2k-1} = F(2k)F(n+1) + F(2k-1)F(n)$

now putting this in to the Eq, of A and B then $AF(2k)F(n+1) + AF(2k-1)F(n) + BF(n) = 1$

now by putting $F(n+1) = F(n+2) - F(n)$

then I will get $AF(2k)F(n+2) + (B+AF(2K-1) - AF(2k))F(n = 1)$

there can be infinite values of A and B satisfying this relation so if I let $A = \frac{1}{F(2k)F(n+2)}$ becaues the first term in the Eq.  will become 1 then $B = \frac{F(2k-2)}{F(2k)F(n+2)}$

By putting this values in the summation I will get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(2k)F(n)F(n+2)} + \frac{F(2k-2)}{F(n+2)F(n+2k)}$

now in the video It is showned that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(n)F(n+2)} = 1$ so I am not going to derive it.

Now putting it we get $\frac{1 + F(2k-2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(n+2)F(n+2k)}}{F(2k)}$

$\frac{1 + F(2k-2)\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(n)F(n+2(k-1))}}{F(2k)}$ in this I have changed the limit.

Now by adding and subtracting some termes I get $Sum(k) = \frac{1 + F(2k-2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(n)F(n+2(k-1))} - \frac{F(2k-2)}{F(2k-1)} - \frac{F(2k-2)}{F(2k)}}{F(2k)}$

Now finnaly I ended up with this $Sum(k) = \frac{1 + F(2k-2)Sum(k-1) - \frac{F(2k-2)}{F(2k-1)} - \frac{F(2k-2)}{F(2k)}}{F(2k)}$

But this is not a direct formulae. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After revising your work, you should find
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F_nF_{n+2k}}=\frac{1}{F_{2k}}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{F_{2j-1}F_{2j}}.$$
The first terms for $k\geq 1$ are $1$, $\frac{7}{18}$, $\frac{143}{960}$, $\frac{4351}{76440}$, $\frac{814001}{37437400}$ (see also OEIS sequence [A333088](https://oeis.org/A333088)).

*Proof*. By induction with respect to $k\geq 1$, we verify that
$$\frac{F_{2k}}{F_nF_{n+2k}}=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{F_{n+2(j-1)}F_{n+2j}}.$$
Indeed, it holds for $k=1$ and, for the inductive step, we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{F_{n+2(j-1)}F_{n+2j}}
=\frac{F_{2k}}{F_nF_{n+2k}}+\frac{1}{F_{n+2k}F_{n+2k+2}}=\frac{F_{2k+2}}{F_nF_{n+2k+2}}.$$
where at the last step we applied [Vajda's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities): $$F_{2k+2}F_{n+2k}-F_{2k}F_{n+2k+2}=(-1)^{2k}F_2F_n=F_n.$$

Hence, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F_nF_{n+2}}=1$ (watch the video or see [Sum $\frac{1}{1\times2}+\frac{1}{1\times3}+\frac{1}{2\times5}+\frac{1}{3\times8}+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729315/sum-frac11-times2-frac11-times3-frac12-times5-frac13-times8)), it follows that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F_nF_{n+2k}}&=
\frac{1}{F_{2k}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{F_{n+2(j-1)}F_{n+2j}}\\
&=\frac{1}{F_{2k}}\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{n+2(j-1)}F_{n+2j}}=\frac{1}{F_{2k}}\sum_{j=1}^k\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^{2(j-1)}\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{F_{2k}}\sum_{j=1}^k\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^{2(j-1)}\left(\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{F_{n+1}F_{n+2}}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{F_{2k}}\sum_{j=1}^k\left(1-1+\frac{1}{F_{2j-1}F_{2j}}\right)
=\frac{1}{F_{2k}}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{F_{2j-1}F_{2j}}.
\end{align}

Comment: How did you reached there ?

Comment: @DhavalBothra Is it clear now?

Comment: yes thank btw can there be an anoather method and sorry if in the question i made any mistake because I am of 13 years.

Comment: @DhavalBothra I don't know... I followed the approach provided in the video.

Comment: Just elaborate the part that You have written in We have that

Comment: @DhavalBothra It is an easy proof by induction. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{1 \over \mrm{F}\pars{n}\mrm{F}\pars{n + 2k}}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over
\mrm{F}^{\, 2}\pars{n + k} - \bracks{\ic^{n}\,\mrm{F}\pars{k}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\,\mrm{F}\pars{k}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{%
{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over \mrm{F}\pars{n + k} - \ic^{n}\,\mrm{F}\pars{k}} -
{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over \mrm{F}\pars{n + k} + \ic^{n}\,\mrm{F}\pars{k}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\mathcal{F}\pars{\mrm{F}\pars{k}/2} -
\mathcal{F}\pars{-\mrm{F}\pars{k}/2} \over 2\,\mrm{F}\pars{k}}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\mathcal{F}\pars{z} \equiv
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over \mrm{F}\pars{n + k} - 2 \ic^{n}\, z}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\pars{z} & \equiv
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over \mrm{F}\pars{n + k} - 2\ic^{n}\, z} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over
\phi^{n + k} - \pars{-1}^{n + k +1}\,\phi^{-n - k} - 2\ic^{n}\, z}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ic}^{n}\phi^{n + k} \over
\phi^{2n + 2k} - 2\ic^{n}z\,\phi^{n + k} - \pars{-1}^{n + k +1}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ic}^{n}\phi^{n + k} \over
\pars{\phi^{n + k} - \ic^{n}\, r_{-}}\pars{\phi^{n + k} - \ic^{n}\, r_{+}}}
\end{align}
$\ds{\ic^{n}\, r_{\pm}}$ are the roots of
$\ds{r^{2} -2\ic zr - \pars{-1}^{n + k + 1} = 0}$. Namely,
$$
r_{\pm} = \pars{z \pm \Delta}\,,\qquad
\Delta \equiv \root{z + \pars{-1}^{k + 1}}
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\pars{z} & =
{1 \over 2}\pars{1 - {z \over \Delta}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over \phi^{n + k} - \ic^{n}\, r_{-}} +
{1 \over 2}\pars{1 + {z \over \Delta}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over \phi^{n + k} - \ic^{n}\, r_{+}}
\end{align}
So, we are left with evaluation of a sum likes
$\ds{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ic}^{n} \over \phi^{n + k} - \ic^{n}\, \xi}\,\right\vert_{\large\ \xi\ \in\ \mathbb{C}}}}$

Comment: does i means root(-1) in the answer

Comment: Yes. Thanks. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I have not accepted it beacuse it is difficult to understand . But yes your answer is really good